# NULL Pointer Exception while implementing Touch Listener in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create simple app through Drag and Touch Listeners. But when I am setting the TouchListener to the TextView Control through inner class, getting `NullPointerException` : Here is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

private TextView option1,  choice1; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    option1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_1);        
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        option1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());  [NULLPOINTER]   
}

private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {

ClipData clipdata = ClipData.newPlainText("","");
DragShadowBuilder shadowbuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(arg0);
arg0.startDrag(clipdata, shadowbuilder, arg0, 0);
return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Change:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    option1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_1);        
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    option1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());   
}
```

To

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    option1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_1);  
    option1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());   
}
```

`findViewById()` looks for a View with the supplied ID in the currently inflated layout. However, you try to use `findViewById()` before calling `setContentView()`, which results in `option1` getting a null value as there is no currently inflated layout. Reordering the statements should fix this